# Assign a children value same as its parent value in type initializer

Tags: c#-4.0, c#-3.0, typeinitializer

I have a class Like

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Address{ get; set; }
    public List<Person> Children{ get; set; }
}
```

Here I have a property Children List.

and Now I am creating an array of this class instances by using type initializer like

```
var persons = new []{
    new Person{ Name="Some Name", Address = "Some Address" },
    new Person{ Name="Some Name 2", Address = "Some Address 2", Children = new List<Person>{
          new Person { Name = "Some Name 3",
                ** Address = <here I want its parent Address>  "Some Address 2" **}
       }
    }
};
```

So, My Problem is that I am creating an object of Person where I assign its Address property and now I want this property value to assign its children, but I am not finding a way to get the its parent like we just do by this keyword to get a class member in its definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way provided by C# to do this. The parent-child relationship between the `Person` object and its children above is not enforced or provided by the language. The easiest way to solve the problem above is store the address in a variable and reference it.

```
string address = "Some Address 2";
var persons = new []{
    new Person{ Name="Some Name", Address = "Some Address" },
    new Person{ Name="Some Name 2", Address = address, 
        Children = new List<Person>{
              new Person { Name = "Some Name 3", address }
       }
    }
};
```

Alternatively, a `Person` object could set the address of any children to itself in a data-binding like arrangement.